# Extracting the suffix of a filename in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Python to create HTML links from a listing of filenames.
The file names are formatted like: song1_lead.pdf, song1_lyrics.pdf.
They could also have names like song2_with_extra_underscores_vocals.pdf. But the common thing is they will all end with _someText.pdf

My goal is to extract just the someText part, after the last underscore, and without the .pdf extension. So song1_lyrics.pdf results with just: lyrics

I have the following Python code getting to my goal, but seems like I'm doing it the hard way.
Is there is a more efficient way to do this?

```py
testString = 'file1_with_extra_underscores_lead.pdf'

#Step 1: Separate string using last occurrence of under_score
HTMLtext = testString.rpartition('_')
# Result: ('file1_with_extra_underscores', '_', 'lyrics.pdf')

#Step 2: Separate the suffix and .pdf extension. 
HTMLtext = HTMLtext[2].rpartition('.')
#Result: ('lead', '.', 'pdf')

#Step 3: Use the first item as the end result.
HTMLtext = HTMLtext[0] #Result: lead
```

I'm thinking what I'm trying to do is possible with much fewer lines of code, and not having to set HTMLtext multiple times as I'm doing now.

Comment: That's 3 lines of code. I'm not sure I'd be concerned about this tbh and it gives you an opportunity to catch exceptions at individual stages

Comment: How about `if testString.endswith('.pdf'): print(testString.split('.pdf')[0])`

Comment: `*_, keep = testString.rsplit('_', maxsplit=1); keep,_ = os.path.splitext(keep)` - only **two** lines.

Comment: One of the answers uses `pathlib`, which treats `paths` as `objects` instead of `strings`.  As such, there are many built-in methods for accessing various parts of the `Path`.  Also see [Python 3's pathlib Module: Taming the File System](https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Path from [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to extract the final path component, without its suffix:

```
from path import Path
Path('file1_with_extra_underscores_lead.pdf').stem.split('_')[-1]
```

outout:

```
'lead'
```

Comment: That worked great, and handles all the files I'm throwing at it.

    from path import Path  
    testFiles = ['song1_with_multiple_underscores_Lead.pdf', 'song1_Lyrics.pdf', 'song2_ChordsF.pdf', 'song2_Lead.pdf']  
    for fn in testFiles:  
      HTMLtext = Path(fn).stem.split('_')[-1] #Gets just the suffix without under_score or .pdf  
      print(HTMLtext + " -> " + fn)
    Result:  
    Lead -> song1_with_multiple_underscores_Lead.pdf  
    Lyrics -> song1_Lyrics.pdf  
    ChordsF -> song2_ChordsF.pdf  
    Lead -> song2_Lead.pdf

Comment: Sorry my code looks a mess. Can't figure out how to comment with code and have it formatted right.

Comment: To avoid splitting the whole string and creating unnecessary list, can change to `str.rpartition('_')[-1]` which is a bit more efficient than `str.rsplit('_', 1)[-1]`

Answer (score 1):

As @wwii said in its comment, you should use [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.path.html?highlight=splitext#os.path.splitext) which is especially designed to separate filenames from their extension and [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=rsplit#str.split)/[`str.rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=rsplit#str.rsplit) which are especially designed to cut strings at a character. Using thoses functions there is several ways to achieve what you want.

Unlike @wwii, I would start by discarding the extension:

```
test_string = 'file1_with_extra_underscores_lead.pdf'
filename = os.path.splitext(test_string)[0]
print(filename)  # 'file1_with_extra_underscores_lead'
```

Then I would use `split` or `rsplit`, with the `maxsplit` argument or selecting the last (or the second index) of the resulting list (according to what method have been used). Every following line are equivalent (in term of functionality at least):

```
filename.split('_')[-1]  # splits at each underscore and selects the last chunk
filename.rsplit('_')[-1]  # same as previous line except it splits from the right of the string
filename.rsplit('_', maxsplit=1)[-1]  # split only one time from the right of the string and selects the last chunk
filename.rsplit('_', maxsplit=1)[1]  # same as previous line except it select the second chunks (which is the last since only one split occured)
```

The best is probably one of the two last solutions since it will not do useless splits.

---

**Why is this answer better than others? (in my opinion at least)**

- Using `pathlib` is fine but a bit overkill for separating a filename from its extension, `os.path.splitext` could be more efficient.
- Using a slice with `rfind` works but is does not clearly express the code intention and it is not so readable.
- Using `endswith('.pdf')` is OK if you are sure you will never use anything else than PDF. If one day you use a `.txt`, you will have to rework your code.
- I love regex but in this case it suffers from the same caveheats than the 2 two previously discussed solutions: no clear intention, not very readable and you will have to rework it if one day you use an other extension.

Using `splitext` clearly indicates that you do something with the extension, and the first item selection is quite explicit. This will still work with any other extension.
Using `rsplit('_', maxsplit=1)` and selecting the last index is also quite expressive and far more clear than a arbitrary looking slice.

Answer (score 0):

This should do fine:

```
testString = 'file1_with_extra_underscores_lead.pdf'
testString[testString.rfind('_') + 1:-4]
```

But, no error checking in here. Will fail if there is no "_" in the string.
You could use a regex as well. That shouldn't be difficult.

Basically I wouldn't do it this way myself. It's better to do some exception handling unless you are 100% sure that there is no need for exception handling.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Fixed that.
Got no active python environment here right now

Comment: Ok, it now works, but you acknowledge that it becomes an issue if the string is not in the expected format. I don't understand what issue is being solved or the OP's motivation. But it works.

Comment: Well, he asked for more efficiency. Based on my knowledge this should be a bit more efficient.
His version uses 2 calls to rpartition and 2 calls to the array operator, plus 2 memory operations.
My version should be more efficient. 1 function call less, 1 array operator less and not writing to the same variable 3 times.
Shouldn't really matter in almost every scenario, but ... well, should be a tiny bit faster

Answer (score 0):

This will work with "..._lead.pdf" or "..._lead.pDf":

```
import re
testString = 'file1_with_extra_underscores_lead.pdf'
m = re.search('_([^_]+)\.pdf$', testString, flags=re.I)
print(m.group(1) if m else "No match")
```