# Extract details from a filename in a folder

Tags: python

My filename looks like `23_10_2020_15_47_06_1550_5.png`.
I want to extract the last `_5` part of it so that I can compare it to another file ending in `23_10_2020_15_47_06_1050_R_5` which is in another folder and use these files for my further operations.

Can someone help me with how to do it?

Comment: What have you tried? Are you familiar with the [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting the suffix of a filename in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57747841/extracting-the-suffix-of-a-filename-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use the [`list.rsplit()`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/rsplit.html) method:

```
from glob import glob

files1 = glob("Folder1\\*.png") # List of all png files in Folder1
files2 = glob("Folder2\\*.png") # List of all png files in Folder2

lst = [f.rsplit('_', 1)[-1][:-4] for f in files1] # List of all the last numbers in the files1 list
```